# What is the wrong with this java code?

Tags: java

I am learning java. The book I'm reading has a question which asks what is wrong with the following code? I have typed the code in NetBeans and I can see the error but why is this error caused and how is it resolved?

The error is highlighted over the code `public A(int t)` and it says

> Constructor B in class B cannot be applied to given types, require int, found no arguments, reason actual and formal arguments lists differ in length.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B b = new B(5);
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public A(int t)  {
        System.out.println("A's constructor is invoked");
    }
}

class B  {
    public B(int k)   {
        System.out.println("B's constructor is invoked");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a contract between `A` & `B` that `A` must call `B`'s constructor, passing it a `int` value...update `A`s constructor to include `super(t);` as the first statement

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand but then I also ask myself why? Why exactly do subclass constructors have to explicitly call super class constructors? What is the reason for this? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: It requires to honor the needs of the parent class.  The parent class simple says, "you can not instantiate me WITHOUT providing me with this information"  A child class is will within its right to create new constructors that take more or less parameters, but it must honor the requirements of the parent.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 4):

when your `super class` has an `args constructor` and doesn't have a no-args constructor you have to explicitly invoke it using a `super(args)` call from sub-class constructor

```
class A extends B {
     public A(int t)  {
         super(t);
            System.out.println("A's constructor is invoked");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the constructor of the super class as the first statement in `A(int)`:

```
public A(int t)  {
   super(t);
   System.out.println("A's constructor is invoked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class B has defined constructor, so it does not have public implicit default constructor (with no arguments). All subclass constructors have to explicitly call superclass constructors, via `super(t)`, if zero argument superclass constructor is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand but then I also ask myself why? Why exactly do subclass constructors have to explicitly call super class constructors?  What is the reason for this? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @JohnW It's about contracts. Superclass can have some 'invariants' - some properties that are always true, like 'field `x` is not `null`'. Without calling constructor, they can not be ensured and rest of applications can not rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

The class B has only one constructor which takes an `int` argument. On the other hand, the constructor you have in class A (implicitly) tries to call a constructor in A's super class (namely B) that takes no arguments. This is the cause of the error. There are at least two ways to fix the problem:

1. Create a no-arg constructor in class B.
2. Explicitly call the constructor in class B which takes an int as a parameter. You can do this using the `super` keyword.

Comment: @JohnW Be sure to upvote the answers you find helpful and accept one as the "official" answer.